# Activate python environment in chroot

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, jupyter, chroot

I need to run commands in a Anaconda Python environment in a chroot with a bash script like this:

```
# install miniconda
chroot $chroot_path /bin/bash /miniconda.sh -f -b -p /miniconda

# Install packages in py2 environment
chroot $chroot_path /bin/bash source /miniconda/bin/activate py2 && /miniconda/bin/conda install notebook ipykernel
```

But I get:

```
/bin/bash: source: No such file or directory
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Try installing Anaconda in the chroot. You get a new version... but code isolation is kinda the point behind chroot anyway.

Comment: @tdelaney What do you mean? Anaconda (miniconda) is installed in the chroot already.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this command

```
chroot $chroot_path /bin/bash source /miniconda/bin/activate py2 && /miniconda/bin/conda install notebook ipykernel
```

First, `source` is a `bash` keyword, not an executable program. When you do `/bin/bash source /miniconda/bin/activate py2` you are trying to run a non-existent executable, which fails. Second, the part after the `&&` will only run after the chroot has been exited. Instead you can use `-c` to run the line as a script

```
chroot $chroot_path /bin/bash -c "source /miniconda/bin/activate py2;/miniconda/bin/conda install notebook ipykernel"
```